# Prevent Core Data persisting object

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data

Is it possible to prevent Core Data to persist an object?

Let's say if I have a `NSManagedObject` subclass with a `BOOL` property `isTemporary`.

So when a save is called on the context I would do a check on the object:

```
if (self.isTemporary) {

 // Do not save

} else {

// Save this object

}
```

**EDIT: More background information for the issue**

Hmm to clarify my issue, I create an object, if it exists already I'm the db I fetch it, if it doesn't exist I insert it and set the the temporary flag of the object to YES. I set the flag because it's not clear at this stage if the user will perform a save or cancel action. If he saves I set the flag temporary to NO. If he cancels then I delete the object if temporary flag is YES.

So far so good, but in the meantime in the background there can occur core data save operations in the background that will persist these objects even though I don't want them persisted (because they should be temporary). So if I'm unlucky and app is killed I could have unwanted objects that have the temporary flag set to YES. One option would be to perform a clean operation on startup of the app to remove objects with temporary flag YES. But everything would be a whole lot easier if it would not persist those objects.

Answer (score 1):

Correct, that is how it can be done.

```
if (self.isTemporary && self.managedObjectContext) {
   [self.managedObjectContext delete:self];
}
```

Note that the `managedObjectContext` of a `NSManagedObject` becomes nil once it is deleted.

Comment: Great but in what method of the `NSManagedObject` subclass do I perform this check? `- (void)willSave`?

Comment: Hmm, do I have to delete the object if I don't want it persisted? I'd rather keep it...

Comment: 1) Yes, `willSave` is the method to override. 2) If you want to keep it, save it ;-) (but keep the isTemporary flag).

Comment: I want to keep it in memory but I don't want it written to file that is...possible?

Comment: It is still in memory if you keep a reference to it even after it calls `delete` on itself.

Comment: I added some more background information for my issue. Maybe from that you can give me a comment...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent `Core Data` from persisting your `ManagedObject`, in other words if you don't want your object to be written in the file, you can achieve this by initializing your `ManagedObject` in following way:

```
@implementation MyManagedObject

- (id) init
{
    NSEntityDescription* entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"MyEntity" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    self = [super initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:Nil];
}

@end
```

Now if you want to save your object, save it in following way:

```
[managedObjectContext insertObject:myManagedObject];
NSError* error;
if ([managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Successfully saveed ManagedObject!");                                                    
} else {
    NSLog(@"Failed to save ManagedObject!");
}
```

Hope this helps!